# How to use Multiple datepicker from same diolog fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

In my app I have to show 4-5 datepickers and set date how to do this using datepicker Dialog fragment ?

currently i have to make separate datepicker for all datepicker dialogs...

```
 public static class RegistrationDatePicker extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(month + "/" + day + "/" + year));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I recently had to use multiple DatePicker DialogFragment in the same activity, I wanted to share my answer.

At first here is my DatePicker DialogFragment, implemented with an interface:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                                implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
// This is the listener for the activity
    private DatePickerFragmentListener listener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Get the current date to start the DatePicker with
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        listener.onDateSet(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }
// This is the method from the DatePicker fragment to implement in the Main Activity
    public interface DatePickerFragmentListener{
        public void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        listener = (DatePickerFragmentListener) context;
    }
}
```

Now the MainActivity that implements the DatePickerFragmentListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements  DatePickerFragment.DatePickerFragmentListener{
    Button myButton1, myButton2;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int DATE_DIALOG = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
        myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);

//        SELECT A START DATE
        myButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DATE_DIALOG = 1;
                openDialog();
            }
        });
//        SELECT A STOP DATE
        myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DATE_DIALOG = 2;
                openDialog();
            }
        });
    }
// I always show the same DatePicker fragment
    public void openDialog(){
        DatePickerFragment datepickDialog = new DatePickerFragment();
        datepickDialog.show(fm, "Start Date");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day) {
//Depending on the DATE_DIALOG key, I update the text of the corresponding button
            if(DATE_DIALOG ==1){
                myButton2.setText(  Integer.toString(day) + "/" +
                                    Integer.toString(month+1)+ "/" +
                                    Integer.toString(year));
            }
            else if(DATE_DIALOG ==2){
                myButton2.setText(  Integer.toString(day) + "/" +
                        Integer.toString(month+1)+ "/" +
                        Integer.toString(year));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: worked great for me. still trying to understand java `interface`. i guess we are sort of wrapping the original `onDateSet` and adding our customer logic via the switch statement. its cool whatever it is. i am assuming i can substitute my own logic in the `MainActivty` `onDateSet` override.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use single DialogFragment for Multiple DatePicker with help of **interface**
You have to create interface in your custom DialogFragment in your case *RegistrationDatePicker* like below:

### CustomDialog.java

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    public interface InterfaceCommunicator {
        void sendRequestCode(int Code);
    }

    String activityCode;
    Button btn;
    public CustomDialog(){
        super();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public CustomDialog(String activityCode, Button btn){
        super();
        this.activityCode = activityCode;
        this.btn = btn;
    }
    InterfaceCommunicator interfaceCommunicator;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(month + "/" + day + "/" + year));
        interfaceCommunicator.sendRequestCode(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        interfaceCommunicator = (InterfaceCommunicator) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        interfaceCommunicator = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

### YourActivity.java

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomDialog.InterfaceCommunicator{

    Button testBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        testBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testBtn);

        testBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CustomDialog d = new CustomDialog("Test", testBtn);
                d.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TestDialog");
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void sendRequestCode(int Code) {
        if (Code == 1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Date Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you